# Body Interactive Images using .Net

Tags: asp.net, wpf-controls

what is the best way to View Body Parts in Interactive Way in ASP.Net  and  also in WinForms

When Mouse over any part of the body it's color will changed, then user can click and add notes about this part?

what about using SVG files for body parts, is there any already SVG for body parts.
what about Flash , OR WPF..

what is the best i can use , Is there any already Tools or controls i can use ..

Comment: you have tagged "wpf-controls" yet mention winforms, which is it?  Also, can you explain what you mean by "Body Parts?" body could apply to parts of an HTML document.

Comment: Perhaps you mean this? 

"How can I highlight arbitrarily shaped regions of the screen (like a country or other complex shape) when the mouse hovers over them?"

Comment: thank IanNorton -  we still in analysis phase, we have to select the best way to do that, firstly i have to deliver some SIMPLE DEMOS then Management will select the best, I have to deliver samples in three way ways, WEB SAMPLE "ASP.NET" , WIN-FORM SAMPLE, and if i can USE 3D in WPF for HUMAN BODY PARTS....like world map, if i move the mouse over Canada , it's color changed,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these useful links.

http://www.biodigitalhuman.com/

http://www.visiblebody.com/demos/head/head_region_demo.html

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html